# Proof of Rows/Columns/Main Diagonals in a normal Magic Square

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, magic-square

Someone else had asked this question but not to enough detail.

I understand that you can sum all of the elements from $1$ to $n^2$ that are in the matrix to get $n^2(n^2+1)/2$. Then from there you can divide by the number of rows, or n that is, to get that each row or column depending on how you look at it should equal $n(n^2+1)/2$.

My question is how does this prove that the diagonals should have this same sum? Or if it does not, how do I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the diagonals have the same sum is that said property is part of the definition of a magic square.

If you just require, in a square grid, that the numbers in each column and in each row add up to the same sum, then the diagonals do not necessarily also add to that sum.  Have a look at
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 7&6&2\\5&1&9\\3&8&4\end{array}
$$

Comment: Oh, I was looking at it wrong. I should have been looking at it as the =1 Sum of main diagonals = Sum of Rows = Sum of columns by definition, and all I would have to know is what the sum was for the rows for instance equals $n(n^2+1)/2$. Then by definition I would know that it is also the sum for all main diagonals and columns.. Thanks! Just was not thinking about it in the right way